# Issues using Resharper6 with Razor

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, razor, resharper

I've just installed the latest and greatest from Resharper, namely version 6. The feature list of this [includes support for Razor](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/whatsnew/index.html#Razor). However, I get some odd errors when using it for Razor. I have the following simple view in `About.cshtml` using Razor:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "About";
}
<h2>About</h2>
```

When I start writing "ViewBag" R#6 helps me autocomplete this word, and when I put in the "." it tells me that "Title" is one of the properties available on the ViewBag-object. However, the ViewBag is underlined with a squiggly line, and the error is:

> One or more types required to compile a dynamic expression cannot be found. Are you missing references to Microsoft.CSharp.dll and System.Core.dll?

Both these dll's are present.. Note that this was a basic example, but I get the same error in every line of Razor code I have.. Some places give a different error-msg though:

> Module 'mscorlib', Version 4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' should be referenced.

Trying to add a reference to this in my project tells me:

> A reference to 'mscorlib' could not be added. This component is already automatically referenced by the build system.

Anyone seen the same errors? How can I fix this and make the squiggly lines go away?

Comment: I do not have the same problem with RS6... And I do not get the suggestion for `Title`. Not even sure how RS6 should know that there is a `Title` property on a dynamic object.

Comment: This isn't a RS6 error, I had the same error from installing the Beta then Release of MVC3, I had to completely uninstall MVC3, then re-install MVC3 for it to work correctly.

Comment: I just installed the official release of MVC3 and R#6, so it surprises me if I have to redo it.. But you had the same problems and this fixed them for you?

Comment: @Ronald: I agree it is odd that it knows about the Title-property, but I just assumed there were some R#-magic going on. However, it turns out you are right.. The reason I got Title on the ViewBag was because I already used it - making R# conclude that there is probably a Title-property it can expose. The same thing happens to not-existing ppts..

Comment: @Phill: Tried reinstalling MVC3 without luck..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is now figured out... It turned out that this was only a problem in our existing projects, and not a problem when starting new projects. In our existing projects we don't have a `Web.Config` file. Instead we have several similarly named config files (`Web.Dev.Config`, `Web.Test.Config`, `Web.Prod.Config`, etc), and we copy one of these into `Web.Config` in our build process. This is a problem for Resharper. Resharper looks for some Razor-references in the projects `Web.Config` file, and when it can't find those references it gets problems parsing your .cshtml-files.

So; be sure to have a `Web.Config` file in the projects that require it if you want to use Resharper with Razor!

Comment: Indeed, nice catch. It may be worth looking at converting the Web.Config's over to use the new built in Web.Config Transformers. So that you can specify different builds configurations with different web.configs. http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/29/vs-2010-web-deployment.aspx (Web Config Transforms)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Answer of stiank81 set me in right direction but I missed some example. I figured it out so here is an example web.config.
So, if resharper says:

> Module 'AssemblyName, Version=1.x.x.xxx, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' should be referenced

then add this web.config to your project

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" >
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="AssemblyName, Version=1.x.x.xxx, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```